# how to solve writeErrors.lenght in mongoDB lib for(let i=0;i<error.writeErrors.length;++i)TypeError:Cannot read properties undefined(reading 'length')

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, mongodb

> server@1.0.0 start
> nodemon index.js

[nodemon] 2.0.21
[nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
[nodemon] watching path(s): *.*
[nodemon] watching extensions: js,mjs,json
[nodemon] starting `node index.js`
Server is running successfully on PORT 8000
D:\ecommerce\server\node_modules\mongoose\lib\model.js:3144
for (let i = 0; i < error.writeErrors.length; ++i) {
^

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'length')
at D:\ecommerce\server\node_modules\mongoose\lib\model.js:3144:47
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...

Please help me out from this problem.

Answer (score 0):

please try one of this in your problem might help you

writeErrors is a property reported by the MongoDB driver

let i = 0; i < 1; ++i

or update your libraries